# JPlayer - Play mp3 files from OnClick links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, jplayer

Hi need a little hand with this script, it plays MP3 files from the **GETSONG.php** file just fine, but I need to post a value (*song id*) back to the **getsong.php** file while playing the mp3, I'm having a little trouble getting it to work, and I need to use a **OnClick** link. When I click this link it tries to change the song, but it looks like the value ***id*** is not passed.

For instance, the value I need to pass from the **OnClick** is **id=101**

This is my link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="my_string('id=101')" > Next Mp3</a>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_string
$(document).ready(function(){

readMP3('test.mp3');// play one mp3 if document is loaded

my_string = function(string_play) {
     dataString_id = string_play;
 readMP3($(this).val(dataString_id));

return true;
}
////////////////////////////////////////
function readMP3(_src){
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("destroy");

 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        var data = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
          url: "getsong.php",
          data: {'ui': _src },
          data_value: {'ui': _src },
          async: false
         }).responseText;

        var string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");

        $('#artist').html(string[1]);
        $('#songname').html(string[2]);
    },
    ended: function (event) {  
        var data = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
          url: "getsong.php",
          data: {'ui': _src },
          data_value: {'ui': _src },
          async: false
         }).responseText;

        var string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");

        $('#artist').html(string[1]);
        $('#songname').html(string[2]);
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3"
}); 

}
})
</script>
```

Please HELP, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using jQuery, I would do capturing of `id` using data attributes which is really handy and click handler like this:

**Example to bind when html is added on first load:**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="next-mp3" data-id="101">Next Mp3</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // your code here...
    // readMP3('test.mp3'); 

    // Click handler for next songs
    $('.next-mp3').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // using $(this).data("id"); will return 101 or any other value

        alert("my next mp3 id: " + $(this).data("id"));

        // your code here...
        // readMP3($(this).data("id"));

    });
});
```

Removed your parts of the code for simplicity, add them as you please.

Here is JsFiddle to see that in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/9gCW2/5/**

**Example to bind when html is added dynamically (after page load):**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="next-mp3" data-id="101">This link will work only after 3 seconds..</a>

<p>Above link will work after 3 seconds..</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Adding some dummy data after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {

        // Dynamically added link
        $('<a href="#" class="next-mp3" data-id="102">Link 2</a>').insertAfter('p');

        // Binding click handlers
        $(document).on('click', '.next-mp3', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            alert("link id: " + $(this).data("id"));
        });

    }, 3000);

});
```

Here is JsFiddle to see this in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/9gCW2/4/**

Comment: The handler works when the link is in the HTML page, it triggets the next-mp3 to play, but when clicking on the same link from a mysql result array it won't work, and the mysql result is outputting the full code:

`<a href="#" class="next-mp3" data-id="101">Next Mp3</a>`

Comment: Ok, the initial question was unclear about this issue so I made it like it is made to data which is loaded at first page load, I updated my code to contain example how to bind dynamically loaded clicks. Does it help?